# How can I make the old region resize adaptively in Java GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

For tuning the Java 6 (1.6.0_23) GC, I use `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC` along with

```
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary
```

My goal is to let the GC compute an optimal ratio between old and new regions. However, visualgc (jvmstat 3.0) shows that while the ratio between the eden and the survivors
is modified according to my workload, the old region remains (desperately) at its initial size, fixed by the `newRatio` (2 in my case).

What is wrong with my settings or expectations?

On my screen, after 19 collections visualgc shows the old Gen constantly under 500m
while the reserved and committed sizes of the old Gen are equal to 624m. 
I have set NewSize to 30m and MaxNewSize to 300m,  but this does not change anything: NewRatio
seems untangible...
PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy only speaks about survivor.

The point is that the "reserved space" menu of visualgc does not show anything for the Old Gen space... 
I have tryed also in using -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary 
without any change.

Here are some logs
`-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCDetails`

There is a full gc, and the final print of the heap... 
It seems that the tenured distribution is garbled, too...

```
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 182096K->66576K(233024K)] 681978K->631994K(932096K), 0.2582390 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs]
116.431: [GC
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 183120K->39952K(233024K)] 748538K->670910K(932096K), 0.1578620 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs]
116.589: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 39952K->0K(233024K)] [ParOldGen: 630958K->310429K(699072K)] 670910K->310429K(932096K) [PSPermGen: 21973K->21973K(30592K)], 1.3326720 secs] [Times: user=1.79 sys=0.01, real=1.33 secs]
118.050: [GC
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 116544K->18448K(233024K)] 426973K->328877K(932096K), 0.0745320 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs]
118.234: [GC
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 134992K->24592K(233024K)] 445421K->351409K(932096K), 0.1290960 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs]
118.526: [GC
Desired survivor size 114884608 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 141136K->36880K(237312K)] 467953K->380085K(936384K), 0.1187320 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.00, real=0.12 secs]
118.759: [GC
Desired survivor size 108593152 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 142446K->40976K(233024K)] 485652K->416957K(932096K), 0.1153230 secs] [Times: user=0.23 sys=0.00, real=0.12 secs]
Heap
PSYoungGen total 233024K, used 97957K (0xb3a40000, 0x9e4f0000, 0x9e4f0000]
eden space 120832K, 47% used [0x9e4f0000,0xa1c95668,0xa5af0000)
from space 112192K, 36% used [0xa5af0000,0xa82f4020,0xac880000)
to space 106048K, 0% used [0xad2b0000,0xad2b0000,0xb3a40000)
ParOldGen total 699072K, used 375981K [0x73a40000, 0x9e4f0000, 0x9e4f0000)
object space 699072K, 53% used [0x73a40000,0x8a96b730,0x9e4f0000)
PSPermGen total 30592K, used 21981K [0x6fa40000, 0x71820000, 0x73a40000)
object space 30592K, 71% used [0x6fa40000,0x70fb7668,0x71820000)
```

Comment: My understanding is that the tenured size grows with increased usage.  I won't expect it to grow much once you application has reached a stable memory usage (possibly very quickly)

Comment: has it done any old collections during this period? I think it only resizes old once it's done a few of them. You may want to use `PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy` as well as verbosegc so you can see what it's doing in detail.

Comment: You didn't mention what your program is doing, but if it's a server, from personal experience I will recommend that you put it under (test) load and tune the GC values to get you the performance you want.  Forget dynamic anything -- better to have something that is somewhat wasteful but known-good under full load.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make the old region resize adaptively in Java GC?

I don't think that it is possible.  The GC has a limited set of "tuning knobs", and I can't see one that would do this for you.  My feeling is that you are "over thinking" the problem.

Reference:

- [A Collection of JVM Options](http://blogs.oracle.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html) by Joseph D. Mocker (Sun Microsystems, Inc.)

If this answer is not good enough, your options are rather limited:

- If you went through the appropriate channels and were prepared to fork out some money, you could probably get some help from an Oracle tuning expert.
- If you had the time and patience, you could try to get your head around the GC source code in the OpenJDK code-base.